# Magento: Need help finding why my layout isn't working

Tags: xml, magento, layout, admin

When I access my custom menu entry's url, the top and the bottom of the admin is showing, but nothing of my block is showing (so my controller is fine, and it's only loading and rendering layout). I wonder if my config is fine for finding my layout or if it's my layout that is badly written.

This is my config.xml extract :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <diaporamaadminrouter>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_Diaporama</module>
                <frontName>diapoconfig</frontName>
            </args>
        </diaporamaadminrouter>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <diaporama>
                <file>edit_diaporamas.xml</file>
            </diaporama>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <menu>
        <diaporama translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Diaporamas</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <diapos translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                    <title>Manage diaporamas</title>
                    <action>diapoconfig/adminhtml_diapos</action>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                </diapos>
                <images translate="title" module="adminhtml">
                    <title>Manage images</title>
                    <action>diapoconfig/adminhtml_images</action>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                </images>
            </children>
        </diaporama>
    </menu>
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <blocks>
       <diaporama>
            <class>Company_Diaporama_Block</class>
       </diaporama>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

This is my layout extract (adminhtml/default/default/layout/edit_diaporamas.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <diaporamaadminrouter_adminhmtl_diapos_index>
     <reference name="content">
             <block type="diaporama/firstdiapoblock" name="display_diapoconfig" template="diaporama/admin_diapos.phtml" />
      </reference>
   </diaporamaadminrouter_adminhtml_diapos_index>
</layout>
```

My block is working in the frontend so, that's not the problem I think. My template is in adminhtml/default/default/template/diaporama, and it's a copy of what's working in the frontend.. I can't manage to find my mistake so please help me :)

Edit : as asked by Meenakshi Sundaram R, here is my controller (both of them have the same function)

```
<?php
class Company_Diaporama_Adminhtml_DiaposController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
          $this->loadLayout();
          $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Comment: show your controller file

Comment: I edited the first post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your layout :

```
<diaporamaadminrouter_adminhmtl_diapos_index>
.........
</diaporamaadminrouter_adminhtml_diapos_index>
```

you write adminhmtl instead of adminhtml in the opening tag. I'm pretty sure the problem is here because Magento cannot parse your xml layout.

Comment: :| :| :| :| :| :|

Thank you :)